# Among Us runs without any GUI and only has audio, how to fix?

Tags: steam, among-us

Somehow my Among Us got broken.

#### When I open the video game Among Us it runs without any GUI window and only has audio, how do I fix the video game?

The only thing I see when it opens is:

- a new item in the taskbar
- audio plays
- there is an icon in the middle of the screen with the among us icon showing and a single transparent "x" that you can click to close the game

I tried uninstall/reinstall numerous times without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

### in a nutshell: wipe the regedit directory named "innersloth"

---

### the longer story:

I searched Google and saw a suggestion from a developer for a different video game suggesting a user to edit a single registry key.

So I took this suggesting further by:

- uninstall the game
- open regedit `windows key + R --> regedit`
- search for "among" in the GUI
- find the "innersloth" directory entry
- delete the entire directory
- install the game
- game suddenly opens fullscreen and works
- success

(maybe related... there was a discord regedit key that i also deleted)

i'm not sure how this happened or why this fixed it.

but i'm sharing because the problem prevents you from playing a game you purchased and hopefully others will benefit from this write up!